# How to broadcast this euclidean distance?

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

So, I have this code, I tried to calculate euclidean distance on each element on list1
it throws an error if list1 has 2 elements, any idea on this?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
list1 =[(10.2,20.2),(5.3,9.2)]
list2 = [(2.2,3.3)]
list1 =np.array(list1)
dist1= distance.euclidean(list1,list2)
print("distance",dist1)
```

prints:

```
ValueError: Input vector should be 1-D.
```

Comment: What result were you expecting? The error and the docs both say 1-D arrays only.

Comment: there 's no other way for this to work?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by 'work'. Were you expecting to get two distances, i.e. from list1[0] to list2[0] then to list1[1] to list2[0]? Or something else? You can probably write a function that does what you want, but it seems that scipy euclidean is not it.

Comment: If list1 has single element it return me a distance, If i add another element on list1 it surely throws me an error based on documentation on scipy, I just want to ask if there is no another way for my code to work when inputs 1 and 2 are not the same in dimensions.Maybe i just  make a for loop for this code to work.

Comment: @ SimonN ,I want to get 2 distances from list1[0] to list2[0] and from list1[1] to list2[0]

Comment: It seems that list2 is  tuple inside list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly manipulate `numpy` arrays in order to find euclidean distances here.

I am assuming either `list1` or `list2` contains `1` element and distances are to be calculated between each element of the other list and the single element. Rest is taken care of by [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```py
import numpy as np
list1 =[(10.2,20.2),(5.3,9.2)]
list2 = [(2.2,3.3)]

a = np.array(list1)
b = np.array(list2)

dist = np.sqrt(((b - a)**2).sum(axis = 1))
```

Output: `dist`

```
array([18.69786084,  6.66483308])
```

where `dist[0]` gives `distance(list1[0], list2[0])` and `dist[1]` gives `distance(list1[1], list2[0])`.

It generalizes even when `list1` has arbitrary number of points, the only constraint is the other list should have only one point.

Answer (score 0):

As you say a for loop is probably easiest here. I have changed your lists to be lists-of-lists rather than lists-of-tuples although I'm not sure that's actually necessary. I don't have scipy installed to check.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
list1 =[[10.2,20.2],[5.3,9.2]]
list2 = [2.2,3.3]
for point in list1:
    dist1= distance.euclidean(point,list2)
print("distance",dist1)
```